# LocalServerReceiver opening Google oauth on localhost but not on Heroku site

Tags: java, heroku, google-drive-api

```
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
```

This is the code for OAUTH 2.0 in google drive API. However, when I ran this on Heroku it didn't work. Are there any fixes ? I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` is for [installed applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#installed_applications). You might want to take a look at [web server applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#web_server_applications).

Comment: @Iamblichus
Yup that's what I ended up doing